# Why property got validate when type conversion error?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have a problem about model validation in ASP.NET Web API. This is a model that have a problem:

```cs
public sealed class AccessTokenRequest
{
    [Required]
    public Guid GameId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string GameAccessToken { get; set; }

    [Range(0, int.MaxValue)]
    public int? Lifetime { get; set; }
}
```

When I passed a string that cannot convert to `Guid` for `GameId`, it is return two validation errors. One is:

`The value 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' is not valid for GameId.`

And another is:

`The value is required.`

I want only the first one to be return. The latter is not make sense since the value is already provided.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest I am not sure whether is is possible without making a custom validation attribute.

The problem is that providing invalid GUID, since it cannot be parsed correctly, it gives `null` as a result. The binder tries to assign `null` to the property with `[Required]` attribute, thus it gives `The value is required.` error.

Let's take a look into `[Required]` attribute:

```
public override bool IsValid(object value)
{
  if (value == null)
    return false;
  string str = value as string;
  if (str != null && !this.AllowEmptyStrings)
    return str.Trim().Length != 0;
  return true;
}
```

as you can see there is a check for a `null` value.

You can either write new attribute from scratch or derive from `RequiredAttribute` and override `IsValid` method.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But `Guid` is a struct. It cannot be `null`.

Comment: @UltimaWeapon - yeah, that's true. It is not the `GameId` that is `null` - the binder tries to assign `null` to this property as a result of failed conversion. I can elaborate on my answer to make it more clear.

Comment: OK, I see. I have override `IsValid` and it is true that it passed `null` to the function. Thank you very much!